# rewrite asp to php based on asp query

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect, asp-classic

I have seen several questions similar and tried all solutions but at a loss. I need to redirect

```
example.com/products.asp?lob=health
```

to

```
example.com/services/healthcare/
```

I need to do this for several lob=*different value*. Is there a way I can redirect each url. Maybe do some kind of rewrite condition on lob but if the value of lob = health, redirect here. If it equals home, redirect somewhere else?

Comment: Are you on IIS and if so, what version?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the "correct" way to do it but it works.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lob=value1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products.asp$ http://example.org/sample/one/? [R=301,L]
```

And then for a different value:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lob=value2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products.asp$ http://example.org/sample/two/? [R=301,L]
```

And then for everything that doesn't match a value:

```
RewriteRule ^products\.asp$ [insert new url here] [R=301,L]
```

The last example also works if you just want to redirect a .asp url to .php. Keep in mind that I have other conditions and rules that are removing the .php extension and adding a / to all files:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
 RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If just looking at a querystring value and then redirecting, try...

```
   Dim theVal, newURL
   If Request("lob") <> "" Then
      theValue = LCase(Request("lob"))
   Else
      theValue = "none"
   End If

   Select Case theValue
      Case "health"
         newURL = "example.com/services/healthcare/"
      Case "law"
         newURL = "example.com/services/legal/"
      Case Else
         newURL = "example.com/services/listing/"
   End Select

   Response.Redirect newURL
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My solution above works in my .htaccess file. I forgot to mention I moved the server from windows to linux. Not sure if that makes a difference in your answer. Is your answer going in the head?

Comment: My answer would be placed at the top of the receiving ASP page.